# Identity Aware Proxy and App Engine Services, One Per Service?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-iap

Is it possible to put more fine-grained access control on AppEngine services using Google Cloud IAP (Identity Aware Proxy)?

I have two services A and B, I want some users to be able to access A, and I would like to provide a different list of users who can access service B. I'd like to use IAP to control access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is available now.

For each service configured for IAP, you can add and allow specific users to each resource or a selection of resources in the Info Panel.

Role: Cloud IAP > IAP-Secured Web App User

---

What is not available is enabling/disabling IAP per service.

Unfortunately once IAP is enabled for App Engine, it is enabled for all App Engine services, and you are therefore unable to have one public App Engine service and one IAP-fronted App Engine service.

Where as IAP can be controlled per HTTPS load balancher

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if Google added this since the question was asked, but now it is possible to control access on individual service level:

[IAP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyIjI.jpg)

Just select the service in the IAP console, and add members to it.  You can add allUsers to make the service public (like in this picture)

Comment: Can you confirm that this works? I've done this and even with "allUsers" it keeps on asking for some Google authentication for a separate service. I wonder if by "public and can be accessed by anyone on the internet" they mean "public to anyone who signs in".

Comment: yep, add "allUsers" to "IAP-secured Web App User".I tried positing a screenshot but there is no "attach" button here.

Comment: Thanks Alexei. You're right. I had tried adding to "viewers" before and was confused it wasn't working. For everybody else, adding to "IAP-secured Web App User" is indeed the solution!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that today is to grant all users of A + B access with IAP, and then do your own additional access control within the service code.

Comment: is it any better with gke/kubnernetes?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to organize your applications under different projects.

Project A contains applications accessible to users in group A, Project B contains applications accessible to users in group B.